# Travelling from Rabbit Island (Cambodia) to Can Tho (Vietnam)

Tags: public-transport, southeast-asia

I am planning my trip to Southeast Asia. In particular, is it feasible to get from [Rabbit Island](https://goo.gl/maps/kWBbAfijvmF2) to [Can Tho](https://goo.gl/maps/HF9aAt5GyZE2) on public transport in one day?

As far as I could figure out from the Lonely Planet:

1. From the island I need to take a boat to Kep
2. From Kep a minibus over the border to Ha Tien
3. And what is the best way to get from Ha Tien to Can Tho?

We will be travelling with kids, so we would like to avoid super early star or late arrival. We are also willing to pay a bit more if it makes the journey substantially faster or nicer.

I read on the Internet that the bus connection from Ha Tien to Can Tho is really poor, would it be possible to arrange a taxi and how much would it cost?

Answer (score 4):

OK, we tried ourselves...

1. From Rabbit Island we took the boat to Kep (about 30 mins).
2. From there we took a tuk-tuk to the Vietnamese border ($15, about 45 mins)
3. We crossed the border on foot (without any issues)
4. On the Vietnamese side there are NO tuk-tuks (despite what Lonely Planet claims), but there is a travel agency there. They sell bus tickets, but we decided to just get a car to the bus station in Ha Tien ($12, 15-20 mins)
5. There we found a bus going directly to Can Tho (about $8, 5h)

It took the whole day and wasn't cheapest ever, but was without major issues.

Comment: $12 for a 15-minute cab ride?  Did you get to keep the cab as a souvenir?

Comment: @Malvolio, unfortunately there were no normal cabs around there and not many people to negotiate with. The distance was 11km, so maybe it took a bit longer - but I agree it was a rip off.